# How to get component in service

Tags: angular

Who can tell me how to get component in service?
example:
in componentA(may be any component)

```
service.call();
```

in service

```
call(){
     how to get component instance or viewContainerRef?
}
```

Comment: Why not just pass it as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have your components implement an interface. You can then pass an argument to your service method. They type of the input argument should be typed to your interface.

```
//component example
class MyComponent implements IComponent {
  someCommonMethodName(){} // method required by interface
}

//service method
doWhatever(component: IComponent) {
  component.someCommonMethodName(); // you can trust that this method exists
}
```